# How to update Android studio with a pom file file downloaded from browser?

Tags: dependencies, pom.xml, android-studio-3.0

I'm getting the old  "Could not resolve com.android.support..." error message. Now I'm sure its a network pr proxy issue from Android studio, but I CAN access the https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/constraint/constraint-layout/1.1.0-beta4/constraint-layout-1.1.0-beta4.pom from my browser and download it directly...BUT how can I use this pom to update Android studio manually in this case?

```
Could not resolve com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta4.
> Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/constraint/constraint-layout/1.1.0-beta4/constraint-layout-1.1.0-beta4.pom'.
      > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/constraint/constraint-layout/1.1.0-beta4/constraint-layout-1.1.0-beta4.pom'.
               > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
                           > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
                                          > unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Comment: come on , no one has a suggestion here??

Answer (score 1):

This drove me nuts so hopefully my answer can help others:

1. Paste this is your chrome browser:
   https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/constraint/constraint-layout/1.1.0-beta4/

you will get a 404 error but you can still download the certificate (developer tools > security > view certificate > drag to your desktop)

2. Delete your current google alias (mine was *.google.com )

keytool -delete -alias *.google.com -keystore /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit

3. Add new certificate you just downloaded to your Android Studio built in JRE :

keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias *.google.com.cer -file /Users/dz5p4d/Downloads/android_certs/*.google.com.cer  -keystore /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts -keypass changeit -storepass changeit